# How can I pass my logback.xml into my akka application as a system property?

Tags: scala, maven, jar, akka, logback

I have an akka application which I wish to package as an uberjar. If I package my application, the logback.xml appears in the root of the jar, but when I start my application I get an error in the configuration log because "URL x is not of type file!" where x is a url which looks like

```
jar:file:/path/to/jar!logback.xml
```

(Error appears here https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/ConfigurationWatchList.java#L90)

This is because the logback file is archived, and so cannot be accessed as a file, which is what logback is expecting. I'm fine with this because the logback config shouldn't feature in a jar because it can result in conflicts. What I want to do is package and run my application, passing in the logback.xml at runtime, e.g

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/full/path/to/logback.xml -jar myapplication.jar
```

When run like this, the logging configuration falls back to the default and I end up with actor logs appearing in my console (It all works as expected when running through maven). Tell me what I'm missing :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's not a good idea to package the `logback.xml` file into your fat jar.  The intention it to have it be configured at runtime.  If you are using `sbt` for assembling the jar, you can specify directories & files to not include by adding to `unmanagedJars`.  For example:

`unmanagedJars in Compile <++= baseDirectory map { dir => 
  (dir ** "logback.xml").classpath 
}`

Then you should be able to pass it in at runtime by including it after `-cp` (classpath) or `-jar`.  For example:

`java -jar -Dlogback.configurationFile=/full/path/to/logback.xml myapplication.jar`

Comment: thank you very much because you are the only one in the whole web who has placed the correct order, afere -jar and before xxx.jar of the "-Dlogback.configurationFile". it was three days that I switched between all the logging frameworks, in test they work and on the server nothing! Thanks again!